# How to fetch table data in Entity Framework and assign it to any Button or Texbox without using where condition

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

How I can do this in Entity Framework?

```
sSQL = "SELECT CategoryName FROM CategorySetup";

if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { Conn.Open(); }

cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, Conn);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

btn_Chicken.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CategoryName"].ToString();
btn_Beef.Text = dt.Rows[1]["CategoryName"].ToString();
btn_Rice.Text = dt.Rows[2]["CategoryName"].ToString();
btn_Drink.Text = dt.Rows[3]["CategoryName"].ToString();
```

How I can do same thing in `Entity Framework 5.0`? If anybody knows, please tell me I'm searching it on google but cant find it, I'm new to `ASP.NET` `MVC` and `Entity Framework`

Comment: There are tons of resources in Entity framework, Please do a google

Comment: Aditya If you have tons of resources so 2 or 3 resources share with me because i didn't find any solution which fix my problem. That's why i posted my question here

Comment: How do you know that row #0 is for the "btn_Chicken", row #1 is for "btn_beef" etc? You don't have any `ORDER BY` in your SQL query, so the order in which the data rows are returned is **not** deterministic! It could suddenly change..... what criteria / column should the data be ordered by? Or how could you determine in EF which object to use for each of the buttons??

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your EF context set up, fetching the data per se is simple:

```
List<CategorySetup> listOfCat = yourDbContext.CategorySetup;
```

But the main question is: ***how*** do you know which of those objects you got back from the database table corresponds to the button in your GUI?? Do you have a column in your database table to **order your data by**? So that you always now row #0 is for `btn_Chicken`, row #1 is for `btn_Beef` ? Or is there a column on the `CategorySetup` table to allows you to find out which `CategorySetup` object to use for which button?

Comment: i was doing it from hard code, But know i m doing it from dynamically Here is code which i used for create button and then assign category to them..

But thanks to all who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    POS_EF_Project.DataBase_Create.POS_Context db = new POS_EF_Project.DataBase_Create.POS_Context();
    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[9];



    public frmTesting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // Display Function
    public void Display(int i)
    {

        string index = buttonArray[i].Tag.ToString();

        var itm = db.ItemSetups.Where(c => c.CatagoryCode == index).OrderBy(c => c.ItemName);

        int iCounter = 0;
        foreach (ItemSetup t in itm)
        {
            fp_Items.Sheets[0].Rows.Count = iCounter + 1;
            fp_Items.Sheets[0].Cells[iCounter, 0].Text = t.ItemCode;
            fp_Items.Sheets[0].Cells[iCounter, 1].Text = t.ItemName;
            fp_Items.Sheets[0].Cells[iCounter, 2].Text = t.Price.ToString();

            iCounter++;
        }


    }

    private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cat = db.Categorys.ToList();

        int horizotal = 6;
        int vertical = 96;

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            buttonArray[i] = new Button();
            buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(168, 40);
            buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(horizotal, vertical);

            buttonArray[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            buttonArray[i].Text = cat[i].CatagoryName;
            buttonArray[i].Tag = cat[i].CategoryCode;

            buttonArray[i].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            buttonArray[i].Image =      (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Basket");

            if ((i + 1) % 9 == 0) horizotal = 6;
            else vertical += 42;

            buttonArray[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.Display(index);

            this.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);



        }
    }

   }
}
```